# Improve Spark denormalization/partition performance

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have a denormalization use case - one hive avro fact table to join with 14 smaller dimension tables and produce a denormalized parquet output table. Both the input fact table and output table are partitioned in the same way (Category=TEST1, YearMonthId=202101). And I do run historical processing, which means processing and loading several months for a given category at once.

I am using Spark 2.4.0/pyspark dataframe, broadcast join for all the table joins, dynamic partition inserts, using coalasce at the end to control the number of output files. (seeing a shuffle at the last stage probably because of dynamic partition inserts)

Would like to know the optimizations possible w.r.t to managing partitions - say maintain partitions consistently from input to output stage such that no shuffle is involved. Want to leverage the fact that the input and output storage tables are partitioned by the same columns.

I am also thinking about this - Use static partitions writes by determining the partitions and write to partitions parallelly - would this help in speeding-up or avoid shuffle?

Appreciate any help that would lead me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of options below that I tried that improved the performance (both time + avoid small files).

1. Tried using repartition (instead of coalesce) in the data frame before doing a broadcast join, which minimized shuffle and hence the shuffle spill.
   -- repartition(count, *PartitionColumnList, AnyOtherSaltingColumn) (Add salting column if the repartition is not even)
2. Make sure that the the base tables are properly compacted. This might even eliminate the need for #1 in some cases, and reduce # of tasks resulting in reduced overhead due to task scheduling.